# Magento admin menu redirect to 404 page

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

Magento admin menu redirect to 404 page

```
<menu>
            <overlay module="adminhtml">
                <title>Popup</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order> 
                <children>
                    <items module="adminhtml">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>package_overlay/adminhtml_overlay</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </overlay>
        </menu>
```